# PHP if else statement in codeigniter view

Tags: php, html, css, codeigniter

Controller:

```
$this->session->set_userdata($data['new_session']);
            $data = array('title' => 'Home',
                          'display' => $this->session->userdata('username'));

            $this->load->view('template/header',$data);
            $this->load->view('template/navbar',$data);
            $this->load->view('pages/home');
            $this->load->view('template/footer');
```

I passed `$data` to my homepage view.

In my header template, this seems to work.

```
  <title><?php if(isset($title)){ echo $title; }?></title>
```

Whenever i load a webpage i always pass `$data['title']` to the header so it changes accordingly, if its home then `$title` should be home, if its login page then `$title` should be login. etc. etc.

In my navbar template:

```
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <?php 
      if(isset($display)){ ?>
      <li><a href=""><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span><?php echo $display; ?></a></li>
      <?php }else{ ?>
        <li><a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>pages/pager/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
      <?php }?>


      </ul>
```

The original problem i had was that it kept showing error of undefined variable `$display`. I got it working somehow, the 2nd problem after that was that although on my homepage it displayed the username of the logged in user instead of Login, whenever i went into view page source it still printed there the error of undefined variable but it wasnt showing on the actual page itself. The 3rd problem now is that i got rid of the 2nd problem by idk how but right now when i go to view page source, this is what shows.

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li><a href="http://localhost/OnlineStories/index.php/pages/pager/login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>


  </ul>
```

How is it that the page source and the actual page are different. On my actual page it clearly displays the username of the logged in user and not Login.

Also whenever i go into view page source it does this.

> Confirm Form Resubmission
>
> This webpage requires data that you entered earlier in order to be
>   properly displayed. You can send this data again, but by doing so you
>   will repeat any action this page previously performed. Press the
>   reload button to resubmit the data needed to load the page.
>   ERR_CACHE_MISS

Also idk if this is vital info but i closed CC cleaner. I had trouble where it kept refreshing after a few seconds/minutes wherein i have to login again. It kept erasing the session.

I don't know if this is much of a problem, its just that i don't understand whats going on and it keeps nagging at me, i cant seem to focus on other stuff.

Comment: Are you absolutely certain that the source you are viewing is from the same page? I noted recently that when i reloaded the source page in chrome that it redirected to the home page even though reloading the page itself did not.

Comment: Yes, idk if there are any other way to get to the page source but what i did to get there was just right click on the page itself then it just pops up there 'view page source' thats what i did.

Comment: thats the normal way yes. I meant the source page itself, i just reloaded it without reopening, if you did that then it could be a different page.

Comment: I don't know. Thats why i'm confused. As far as what i'm doing, i accessed that specific page's source so it should show the same. It also worth mentioning getting Confirm Form Resubmission whenever i try to get into the source page after logging in.

Comment: @John what happens when you reload the source page itself as Chris suggested? Also, can you share the part where you actually set the `username` in the session data? From the above we can only see the array `$data` being set with a single item named 'new_session', then you overwrite the existing item by assigning `$data` a new array element to it in the next line.